# Passing "%20" into a string to be encoded as a URL without it converting to a space?

Tags: url, go, encode, urlencode, sign

I have the following code to post data to a site: https://play.golang.org/p/e1g0Nd1kDh0

When I view the request in Fiddler, it shows as:

```
"jobTitle=Area Manager"
```

What I want it to do is send the string *exactly* as it is in the code (i.e. not encode the %20 to spaces), as it seems to be causing some confusion on the other side? An identical request made using a Python program works fine where the spaces are not added.

I've tried escaping it by doubling the % signs, but it doesn't seem to work. Any help would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Be sure to specify a timeout when you create a client, e.g.
       client := &http.Client {
           Timeout: time.Second * 10,
       }

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to receive a literal `%20` on the server side, then encode the `%` sign. It encodes to `%25`. So your postdata becomes:

```
    data := "&jobTitle=Area%25%20Manager"
```

But if this is happening, there is probably a problem on the server side where the postdata is being decoded twice.

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass the URL encode characters individually. In this case %25%32%30 = "%20"

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30747848)